# Json object and image posting with multipart/form-data in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I am trying to post an image along with the json object the image got uploaded in s3 bucket successfully but the json object got encoded and the controller cant parse the same json

I consoled the posted json the sample json is

{ 
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx",',
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx",',
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx",',
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx",',
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx",',
  '%xxxx%22': '"xxxx"' }

Comment: Can't tell much without looking at your code.

Comment: Where you put the json object,  http header or body?

Comment: i added it in to the request body